# Can someone help me with the databricks timestamp/timezone syntax issue that im facing while executing my query?

Tags: databricks-sql

I am moving my data pointing from SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) to Databricks. There will be syntax change in the query in databricks as compared to SSMS query. I am not familiar with databricks. So, I am trying to do the same query in databricks as well but, it is showing me error. How should i correct the syntax now? The error is where the conversion is happening to PST timezone. Can anyone help me with this ?

The SQL query is:

```
select  
    case 
        when category_name = 'Hardware' then 'Hardware'
        when category_name = 'Services' then 'Services'
        when category_name = 'Software' then 'Software'
        when category_name = 'Subscription' then 'Cloud' 
    end as category_name,
    sum(item_price * line_item_quantity) as order_amount,
    CUSTOMER_ID 
from 
    curated_delta.order_details 
where 
    parentkit_id = 0 
    and category_name in ('Hardware', 'Software', 'services', 'Subscription')
    and category_name is not null 
    and order_date >= cast(cast(dateadd(dd, -365, convert(datetime, sysdatetimeoffset() AT TIME ZONE 'pacific standard time')) as date) as datetime) 
group by 
    category_name, CUSTOMER_ID 
order by 
    1
```

The error I get is:

> Error in SQL statement: ParseException:
> no viable alternative at input 'cast(cast(dateadd(dd,-365,convert(datetime,sysdatetimeoffset() AT'(line 6, pos 79)

Comment: I get the same error message in a NOTEBOOK `%%sql` cell, in azure synapse analytics, when I execute `cast(NOW()  AT TIME ZONE 'Greenwich Standard Time'  AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time'  as DATETIME)`